# Reading a line of integers in Python

Tags: python

I am beginner in Python and I am solving a question at CodeChef where I have to read a line of space separated integers. This is what I am doing:

```
def main():

  t=int(raw_input())    #reading test-cases

  while t!=0:
    n, k=raw_input().split()    #reading a line of two space separated integers
    n, r=int(n), int(r)    #converting them into int
    list=[]
    #reading a line of space separated integers and putting them into a list
    list[-1:101]=raw_input().split()
```

Now I to convert each element in the list to integer. Is there some better way to to do this? Please suggest an online resource where I can play with Python and learn tips and tricks!

Comment: what is the the purpose of t?

Comment: and why you read two integers and what are you trying to do with `[-1:101]` slice?

Comment: reading two integers is a part of solution, pay no attention to that. Coming to slice, since I have to read a line of space separated integers and put them into a list, I am using list[-1:101]. There won't be more than 100 numbers. So using this and split(), all numbers (in form of string) are stored in the list.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In Python 2, you could write:

```
numbers = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

This reads a line, splits it at white spaces, and applies `int()` to every element of the result.

If you were using Python 3, the equivalent expression would be:

```
numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

or

```
numbers = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
```

Comment: What if my input is like "insert 3 3" meaning first string and then 2nd and 3rd int? (PYTHON 3)

Comment: @DipenBakraniya You can read all of them as `str` and later convert each of them to their expected types

Answer (score 1):

`map(int, list)` should solve your problem

Comment: You can also try [int(i) for i in list]